# convert temperature from decimal to whole using xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, converters, weather, temperature

just curious how will I define the following in forms.

c#

```
 weather.Temperature = (string)results["main"]["temp"]  ;
```

xaml

```
<Label x:Name="tempLabel"
            Text="{Binding Temperature , StringFormat='{0}°'F}"/>
```

my current result :  270.50 
  it should be 83 F

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what is the actual value in results["main"]["temp"]?  And you should really store temperature as a numeric value, not a string

Comment: From your binding is everything ok. You want to change one number to other? Use Converter

Comment: the actual value in results is 270.50 , so yes I will need some type of converter . do you know any example that I could follow ?

Comment: What are you converting?  What units is the source value in?

Comment: your not giving us the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disragarding the conversion °F<->°C you can use the format string to display whole numbers only

```
<Label x:Name="tempLabel"
    Text="{Binding Temperature , StringFormat='{0:F0}°F'}"/>
```

(please note, that I moved the 'F' within the quotation marks in order to be displayed correctly). The `F0` format string is a fixed decimals floating point formatter with zero decimals. `F1` would have one decimal number, `F2` two and so on. If you'd like to read more about the format strings for numbers, please see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

To convert the °C value to °F you could for example use an `IValueConverter` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Binding_Value_Converters)), or convert the value directly in your viewmodel.

**EDIT**

I missed the point that `Temperature` was a `string`. In order to use the number formatting, `Temperature` has to be a number. Convert it the following way

```
weather.Temperature = double.Parse((string)results["main"]["temp"])
```

(of course you'll have to change the type of the `Temperature` property to `double?`);

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert the temperature manually, from Celsius to Fahrenheit vice-versa whatever you want to (Please look into this over the net, the formula it is). By conversion from decimal to whole number, you can use `Math.Round(yourNumber, 0);`. Then bind the result to your `XAML`.

**EDIT**: You can also do this by using a converter `{Binding value, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}` so that the code would be reusable

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = value.ToString();
    item = //your fahrehnheit converter formula 
          //do necessary conversions string to double etc.
    return item;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the service let me define the units , all I need to do is add 
 **&units=imperial**
 as a parameter to the service call and it will return the temperature in Fahrenheit. 
Also , I applied @Paul Kertscher edit to display only the whole number. 
Thank you all for your answers.